# install glassfish independently, or from netbeans?

Tags: ubuntu, java, mysql, webserver, glassfish

I'm running Ubuntu on a desktop and laptop, and use Netbeans as an IDE.  On the desktop, `$/glassfish-4.1` has everything configured properly.  I may have copied a JAR for MySQL over to the libs folder, but didn't otherwise configure Glassfish itself.  Unfortunately, I can't remember or quite replicate how I installed Glassfish on the desktop.

On the laptop, I just want to install Glassfish exactly as on the desktop.  However, when I install Glassfish as bundled with Netbeans, and then start up the JDBC connection pool options, and create a new connection pool, there are only four or so connection parameters.

Alternately, on the desktop, starting a new JDBC connection pool, there are over 200 properties.

How do I install Glassfish so that it has all these connection parameters:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/534320/jdbc-connection-pool-details-on-glassfish

I'm just using Glassfish for rapid prototyping and development, and just want to dip my toe in, but am willing to dive in if need be.

However, why would one instance of Glassfish, installed quite recently, have dramatically different out-of-the-box configuration than another?

laptop, from the netbeans version:

```
thufir@freegeek:~$ 
thufir@freegeek:~$ glassfish
glassfish4/    glassfish-4.1/ 
thufir@freegeek:~$ glassfish4/glassfish/bin/asadmin start-domain
Waiting for domain1 to start ..................
Successfully started the domain : domain1
domain  Location: /home/thufir/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1
Log File: /home/thufir/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log
Admin Port: 4848
Command start-domain executed successfully.
thufir@freegeek:~$
```

[image: glassfish-4.1]

and from the download from Glassfish website:

```
thufir@freegeek:~$ 
thufir@freegeek:~$ glassfish
glassfish4/    glassfish-4.1/ 
thufir@freegeek:~$ glassfish4/glassfish/bin/asadmin start-domain
Waiting for domain1 to start .....
Successfully started the domain : domain1
domain  Location: /home/thufir/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1
Log File: /home/thufir/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log
Admin Port: 4848
Command start-domain executed successfully.
thufir@freegeek:~$
```

gives the same small number of parameters as the other "version", or other instance, of glassfish installed on the **laptop**.  Neither laptop version is giving me the catalog of options which are available on the Desktop for JDBC Connection Pooling with Glassfish.

On the desktop, creating a new JDBC connection pool comes with a multitude of pre-populated parameters:

[image: Glassfish on desktop parameters]

see also:

https://java.net/projects/glassfish/lists/users/archive/2014-11/message/1

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting difference, and not one I've come across before. JDBC connection properties are mostly optional, there are only a couple that are actually needed. You can click the "Add Property" button to give you another key/value pair which you can then populate with whatever property you want.

[Here is the GlassFish 4 administration guide](https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/administration-guide.pdf), which will tell you all about the available properties which GlassFish will recognise. Page 238, section 12-6, tells you about the `create-jdbc-connection-pool` command for `asadmin` and says:

> You can also view the full syntax and options of the subcommand by
>   typing asadmin help create-jdbc-connection-pool at the command line.

That might be a bit of a hassle to do if you have a lot of properties which need to be set, so there is an alternative for your situation.

Since you already have everything configured just right on your desktop, there is nothing stopping you from zipping your top level GlassFish directory and unzipping right on your laptop. You can then add an existing server in Netbeans and point it to the copied directory. I wouldn't recommend doing that sort of thing in production, but it will probably make things much easier for development purposes.